# Text being entered not where cursor is, in VBA Project window

Tags: vba, excel

I have this string:

```
Admin_List = "`{&"
```

For whatever reason my cursor in VBA project window is bonker when trying to work with this string. If I try to add a comma after the `{` it lands after the `&`

Any idea what is causing this wacky behavior?
Thank you :)

Comment: I put that string in and it's not a problem here.  Have you been editing that module a lot?

Comment: might be some kind of invisible character that didn't post on this site when I setup this thread.

Comment: always possible.  I don't know what the white space conspiracy holds, but there's something behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes working in (editing) modules can cause wackiness.  I have found that macros can sometimes hang without throwing an error, and other such strangeness.  In these cases I usually copy the contents of the module into another module (removing leading and trailing white space) and delete the old module.  Then I save, close, re-open.  This isn't a silver bullet, but it has definitely solved some odd behavior for me in that past.  You may also recognize that your workbook shrinks by a few kilobytes, this is pretty normal.